# Bond Option Hedging

Tags: interest-rates, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-volatility, short-rate

### (My question)

Please  show me how to solve  from (2) to (4) with computation processes.
These are too difficult to solve.

## Thank you for your help in advance.

---

### (Cross-link)

I have posted the same question on https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3347148/bond-option-hedging/3349320#3349320

---

### (Original questions)

Exercise 7.4 Bond Option Hedging

Consider a portfolio $(\xi^T_t, \xi^S_t)_{t \in [0, T]}$ made of two bonds with maturities $T$, S, and value
\begin{eqnarray}
V_t=\xi^T_t P(t, T) + \xi^S_t  P(t, S)
\end{eqnarray}
at time $t$, and assume that it hedges the bond call option payoff $( P(T, S) - \kappa )^+$, so that we have
\begin{eqnarray}
V_t &=& E \left[ \exp \left( - \int^T_t r_s ds \right) \cdot ( P(T, S) - \kappa )^+ \middle| \mathcal{F}_t \right]  \\
&=& P(t, T) E^{ \tilde{\mathbb{P}} }  \left[  ( P(T, S) - \kappa )^+ \middle| \mathcal{F}_t \right] 
\end{eqnarray}

(1) Assume that $( \sigma^T_t)_{t \in [0, T]}$ and $( \sigma^S_t)_{t \in [0, S]}$ are deterministic functions, show that the price of a bond option with strike $\kappa$ can be written as
\begin{eqnarray}
&&  E \left[ \exp \left( - \int^T_t r_s ds \right) \cdot ( P(T, S) - \kappa )^+ \middle| \mathcal{F}_t \right] \nonumber  \\
&& \qquad \qquad =  P(t, T) E^{ \tilde{\mathbb{P}} }  \left[  ( P(T, S) - \kappa )^+ \middle| \mathcal{F}_t \right]    \\
&& \qquad \qquad =  P(t, T) C(X_t, \kappa, v(t, T) ) \\
&& \qquad \qquad =  P(t, T) C(X_t, \kappa, \sigma)
\end{eqnarray}
where $X_t$ is the forward price $X_t \equiv P(t, S)/P(t, T)$,
\begin{eqnarray}
v^2(t, T) = \int^T_t \left( \sigma^S_u - \sigma^T_u  \right)^2 du
\end{eqnarray}
and $C(X_t, \kappa, \sigma)$ is a function to be determined. Recall that if $X$ is a centered Gaussian random variable with mean $m_t$ and variance $v^2_t$ given $\mathcal{F}_t$, we have
\begin{eqnarray}
E \left[ \left( e^X - K \right)^+ | \mathcal{F}_t \right] &=& e^{ m_t + v^2_t /2 } N \left( \frac{v_t}{2} + \frac{1}{v_t} \left( m_t + \frac{v^2_t}{2}  - \log K \right) \right) \nonumber \\
&& \qquad - K N \left( - \frac{v_t}{2} + \frac{1}{v_t} \left( m_t + \frac{v^2_t}{2}  - \log K \right) \right)
\end{eqnarray}
where $N(x)$, $x \in \mathbb{R}$, denotes the Gaussian distribution function, cf. Lemma 2.3.

(2) We assume that the portfolio $(\xi^T_t, \xi^S_t)_{t \in [0, T]}$ is self-financing, i.e.
\begin{eqnarray}
dV_t=\xi^T_t dP(t, T) + \xi^S_t  dP(t, S)
\end{eqnarray}
Show that the forward portfolio price $\hat{V_t} \equiv V_t/P(t, T)$ satisfies

\begin{eqnarray}
d\hat{V_t}=\frac{ \partial C(X_t, \kappa, v(t, T) ) }{ \partial x } d X_t.
\end{eqnarray}

(3) Show that we have
\begin{eqnarray}
dV_t &=& \left( \hat{V_t} - \frac{ P(t, S) }{ P(t, T) } \frac{ \partial C( X_t, \kappa, v(t, T) ) }{ \partial x }  \right) dP(t, T)  \nonumber \\
&& + \frac{ \partial C(X_t, \kappa, v(t, T) ) }{ \partial x } dP(t, S) 
\end{eqnarray}

(4) Compute the hedging portfolio strategy $(\xi^T_t, \xi^S_t)_{t \in [0, T]}$ of the bond call option on $P(T, S)$.

---

## (1) My answer

- This dynamics of $dP(t, T)$ uses $\sigma^T_t$ as its volatility instead of $\zeta^T_t$ on the text page 89. Namely, the dynamics of $dP(t, T)$ is a same type of Exercise 7.3. Therefore, recall the result of Exercise 7.3.(1). On the other words, recall the results of Exercise 4.3.(5). Besides, $d B^T_t = d B_t   - \sigma^T_t dt $. Or, recall Exercise 7.1.(4) and Exercise 7.1.(7).  Exercise 7.1 uses $\zeta_t$ instead of $\zeta^T_t$ as the volatility on its dynamics of $dP(t, T)$.
  \begin{eqnarray}
  \frac{ dP(t, T)}{P(t, T)} &=& r_t dt + \sigma^T_t dB_t \\
  \frac{P(T, S)}{P(T, T)}&=&\frac{P(t, S)}{P(t, T)}  \exp \left( \int^T_t \left( \sigma^S_u - \sigma^T_u \right) d B^T_u \right) \nonumber \\
  && \qquad \qquad \cdot  \exp \left( -  \frac{1}{2} \int^T_t \left(  \sigma^S_u -\sigma^T_u  \right)^2 du  \right) \\
  P(T, S)&=&\frac{P(t, S)}{P(t, T)}  \exp \left( \int^T_t \left( \sigma^S_u - \sigma^T_u \right) d B^T_u \right) \nonumber \\
  && \qquad \qquad \cdot  \exp \left( -  \frac{1}{2} \int^T_t \left(  \sigma^S_u -\sigma^T_u  \right)^2 du  \right) 
  \end{eqnarray}
- Let $m(t, T)$ and $v^2(t, T)$ as below.
  \begin{eqnarray}
  m(t, T) &=& \log \frac{P(t, S)}{P(t, T)} -  \frac{1}{2} \int^T_t \left(  \sigma^S_u -\sigma^T_u  \right)^2 du \\
  v^2(t, T) &=& \left( \int^T_t \left( \sigma^S_u - \sigma^T_u \right) d B^T_u  \right)^2  \\
  &=& \int^T_t  \left( \sigma^S_u - \sigma^T_u \right)^2 du \\
  m(t, T) + \frac{ v^2(t, T) }{2} &=& \log \frac{P(t, S)}{P(t, T)}
  \end{eqnarray}
- Substitute the above result into the expectation value.
  \begin{eqnarray}
  &&  E \left[ \exp \left( - \int^T_t r_s ds \right) \cdot ( P(T, S) - \kappa )^+ \middle| \mathcal{F}_t \right] \nonumber  \\
  && \qquad \qquad =  E^{ \tilde{\mathbb{P}} } \left[ \frac{ P(t, T) }{ P(t, T) } \exp \left( - \int^T_t r_s ds \right) \cdot ( P(T, S) - \kappa )^+ \middle| \mathcal{F}_t \right]    \\
  && \qquad \qquad = P(t, T) E^{ \tilde{\mathbb{P}} } \left[ \frac{ 1 }{ P(T, T) } ( P(T, S) - \kappa )^+ \middle| \mathcal{F}_t \right]    \\
  && \qquad \qquad = P(t, T) E^{ \tilde{\mathbb{P}} } \left[  ( P(T, S) - \kappa )^+ \middle| \mathcal{F}_t \right]    
  \end{eqnarray}
- Recall the result of Exercise 7.1.(7). Here, let $m(t, T) =m$, $v(t, T)=v$, and $\kappa=K$.
  \begin{eqnarray}
  && E^{\mathbb{P}} \left[ \exp \left(- \int^T_t r_s ds \right) \cdot ( P(T,S) - K )^+  \middle| \mathcal{F}_t \right]  \nonumber \\
  && \quad = P(t, T) e^{m+ v^2/2} N\left(  v + \frac{m - \log K}{v} \right) -P(t, T)  K N\left( \frac{m - \log K}{v} \right)  \\
  && \quad = P(t, T) \frac{P(t,S) }{P(t,T)}  N\left(  v  - \frac{v}{2}  +  \frac{1}{v} \log \frac{P(t,S) }{K \ P(t,T)} \right)  \nonumber \\
  && \qquad -P(t, T)  K N\left( - \frac{v}{2}  +  \frac{1}{v} \log \frac{P(t,S) }{K \ P(t,T)}\right)  \\
  && \quad = P(t,S)   N\left(   \frac{v}{2}  +  \frac{1}{v} \log \frac{P(t,S) }{K \ P(t,T)} \right)  \nonumber \\
  && \qquad -P(t, T)  K N\left( - \frac{v}{2}  +  \frac{1}{v} \log \frac{P(t,S) }{K \ P(t,T)}\right)   \\
  && \quad = P(t, T) \frac{ P(t,S) }{ P(t, T) }  N\left(   \frac{v}{2}  +  \frac{1}{v} \log \frac{P(t,S) }{K \ P(t,T)} \right)  \nonumber \\
  && \qquad -P(t, T)  K N\left( - \frac{v}{2}  +  \frac{1}{v} \log \frac{P(t,S) }{K \ P(t,T)}\right)  \\
  && \quad = P(t, T) C\left( \frac{ P(t,S) }{ P(t, T) } , K, v \right) \\
  && \quad = P(t, T) C(X_t, \kappa, v(t, T) ) \\
  && \quad  =  P(t, T) C(X_t, \kappa, \sigma)
  \end{eqnarray}

$\square$

---

(2) ??? This is too difficult to solve!

### Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### I solved from (2) to (4) by myself !

### (2) My answer

- Use the result of (1) with keeping in mind that the following R.H.S is $\mathcal{F}_t $ measurable.
  \begin{eqnarray}
  V_t &=& E^{\mathbb{P}} \left[ \exp \left(- \int^T_t r_s ds \right) \cdot ( P(T,S) - K )^+  \middle| \mathcal{F}_t \right] \\
  &=& P(t, T) E^{ \tilde{\mathbb{P}} } \left[  ( P(T, S) - \kappa )^+ \middle| \mathcal{F}_t \right]    \\
  &=&  P(t, T) C(X_t, \kappa, v(t, T) ) 
  \end{eqnarray}
- Therefore,
  \begin{eqnarray}
  \hat{ V_t }&=& \frac{ V_t }{P(t, T)} \\
  &=&  E^{ \tilde{\mathbb{P}} } \left[  ( P(T, S) - \kappa )^+ \middle| \mathcal{F}_t \right]    \\
  &=& C(X_t, \kappa, v(t, T) ) 
  \end{eqnarray}
- First, use It$\hat{o}$'s formula on the L.H.S.
  \begin{eqnarray}
  d \hat{ V_t }&=& 0 \ dt + d \hat{ V_t } + \frac{1}{2} \ 0 \ d [ \hat{ V_t }] \\
  &=& d \hat{ V_t } 
  \end{eqnarray}
- Second, recall the result of (1), $C(X_t, \kappa, v(t, T) ) $.
  \begin{eqnarray}
  C(X_t, \kappa, v(t, T) ) &=& \frac{ P(t,S) }{ P(t, T) }  N\left(   \frac{v}{2}  +  \frac{1}{v} \log \frac{P(t,S) }{\kappa \ P(t,T)} \right)  \nonumber \\
  && \qquad -  \kappa N\left( - \frac{v}{2}  +  \frac{1}{v} \log \frac{P(t,S) }{\kappa\ P(t,T)}\right)  \\
  &=& X_t  N\left(   \frac{v}{2}  +  \frac{1}{v} \log \frac{X_t}{\kappa } \right)  \nonumber \\
  && \qquad - \kappa N\left( - \frac{v}{2}  +  \frac{1}{v} \log \frac{X_t }{\kappa }\right)  
  \end{eqnarray}
- Third, use It$\hat{o}$'s formula on the R.H.S.
  \begin{eqnarray}
  d C(X_s, \kappa, v(s, T) )  &=& 0 \ ds +  \partial_x C(X_s, \kappa, v(s, T) )  dX_s + \frac{1}{2} \ 0 \ d [ X_s ] \\
  \int^t_0 d C(X_s, \kappa, v(s, T) )  &=& \int^t_0 \partial_x C(X_s, \kappa, v(s, T) )  dX_s \\
  C(X_t, \kappa, v(t, T) ) &=& C(X_0, \kappa, v(0, T) )  \nonumber \\
  && \qquad+ \int^t_0 \partial_x C(X_s, \kappa, v(s, T) )  dX_s \\
  &=&  E^{ \tilde{\mathbb{P}} } \left[  ( P(T, S) - \kappa )^+ \middle| \mathcal{F}_t \right]   \nonumber \\
  && \qquad + \int^t_0 \partial_x C(X_s, \kappa, v(s, T) )  dX_s 
  \end{eqnarray}
- Substitute the above result into $\hat{ V_t }$.
  \begin{eqnarray}
  \hat{ V_t }&=&C(X_t, \kappa, v(t, T) ) \\
  &=&  E^{ \tilde{\mathbb{P}} } \left[  ( P(T, S) - \kappa )^+ \middle| \mathcal{F}_t \right]   + \int^t_0 \partial_x C(X_s, \kappa, v(s, T) )  dX_s 
  \end{eqnarray}
- Moreover,
  \begin{eqnarray}
  E^{ \tilde{\mathbb{P}} } \left[  ( P(T, S) - \kappa )^+ \middle| \mathcal{F}_t \right]  &=& E^{ \tilde{\mathbb{P}} } \left[  ( P(T, S) - \kappa )^+ \middle| \mathcal{F}_t \right]   \nonumber \\
  && \qquad + \int^t_0 \partial_x C(X_s, \kappa, v(s, T) )  dX_s \\
  \int^t_0 \partial_x C(X_s, \kappa, v(s, T) )  dX_s &=&0
  \end{eqnarray}
- Therefore,
  \begin{eqnarray}
  \hat{ V_t }&=&C(X_t, \kappa, v(t, T) ) \\
  &=&  E^{ \tilde{\mathbb{P}} } \left[  ( P(T, S) - \kappa )^+ \middle| \mathcal{F}_t \right]   
  \end{eqnarray}
- On the other hand, hence,
  \begin{eqnarray}
  \hat{ V_t } &=& C(X_t, \kappa, v(t, T) ) \\
  d \hat{ V_t } &=& d C(X_t, \kappa, v(t, T) ) \\
  &=& \partial_x C(X_t, \kappa, v(t, T) )  dX_t 
  \end{eqnarray}

$\square$

---

### (3) My answer

- Use It$\hat{o}$'s formula.
  \begin{eqnarray}
  d V_t &=& d (P(t, T) \cdot \hat{ V_t } ) \\
  &=& \partial_t (P(t, T) \cdot \hat{ V_t } ) dt  \nonumber \\
  && \quad  +  \hat{ V_t } \partial_x P(t, T) |_{x=P(t,T)} dP(t,T)  + P(t, T) \partial_y \hat{ V_t } |_{y=\hat{ V_t } } d \hat{ V_t } \nonumber \\
  && \quad  +  \frac{1}{2}  \hat{ V_t } \partial_{xx}  P(t, T) |_{x=P(t,T)} d[ P(t,T) ] +   \frac{1}{2} P(t,T) \partial_{yy}  \hat{ V_t } |_{y=\hat{ V_t }} d[ \hat{ V_t } ]  \nonumber \\
  && \quad  +  \frac{1}{2} \partial_{xy} (P(t, T) \cdot \hat{ V_t } ) |_{x=P(t,T), y=\hat{ V_t }} d[ P(t,T) ,  \hat{ V_t } ]  \nonumber \\
  && \quad+  \frac{1}{2} \partial_{yx} (P(t, T) \cdot \hat{ V_t } ) |_{ y=\hat{ V_t }, x=P(t,T)} d[ \hat{ V_t }, P(t,T)  ] \\ 
  &=&  \hat{ V_t }dP(t,T)  + P(t, T) d \hat{ V_t } + d[ \hat{ V_t }, P(t,T)  ]
  \end{eqnarray}
- Use the result of (2).
  \begin{eqnarray}
  d V_t &=& \hat{ V_t }dP(t,T)  + P(t, T) d \hat{ V_t } + d[ \hat{ V_t }, P(t,T)  ] \\
  &=& \hat{ V_t }dP(t,T)  + P(t, T) \partial_x C(X_t, \kappa, v(t, T) )  dX_t  \nonumber \\
  && \quad   + \partial_x C(X_t, \kappa, v(t, T) ) dP(t, T) dX_t \\
  &=& \hat{ V_t }dP(t,T)  -  \partial_x C(X_t, \kappa, v(t, T) )  X_t dP(t, T) \nonumber \\
  && \quad + \partial_x C(X_t, \kappa, v(t, T) )  X_t dP(t, T) \nonumber \\
  && \quad + \partial_x C(X_t, \kappa, v(t, T) )  P(t, T)  dX_t  \nonumber \\
  && \quad + \partial_x C(X_t, \kappa, v(t, T) ) dP(t, T) dX_t 
  \end{eqnarray}
- Here, one computes the dynamics of $P(t, S)$ using the definition of $X_t=P(t, S)/P(t, T)$ by It$\hat{o}$'s formula.
  \begin{eqnarray}
  d P(t, S) &=& d(X_t P(t, T)) \\
  &=& \partial_t  (X_t P(t, T)) dt  \nonumber \\
  && \quad  + P(t, T) \partial_x X_t |_{x=X_t} dX_t + X_t \partial_y P(t, T) |_{y=P(t, T)} dP(t, T)  \nonumber \\
  && \quad  + \frac{1}{2} P(t, T) \partial_{xx}  X_t |_{x=X_t} d [X_t ]  \nonumber \\
  && \quad  + \frac{1}{2} X_t  \partial_{yy}  P(t, T) |_{y=P(t, T)} d [P(t, T) ]  \nonumber \\
  && \quad  + \frac{1}{2} \partial_{xy} (X_t P(t, T))  |_{x=X_t, y=P(t,T)} d[ X_t, P(t,T) ] \nonumber \\
  && \quad  + \frac{1}{2} \partial_{yx} (X_t P(t, T))  |_{y=P(t,T), x=X_t} d[P(t,T),  X_t ]  \\
  &=&  P(t, T) dX_t + X_t dP(t, T)  + d[ X_t, P(t,T) ]  \\
  &=&  P(t, T) dX_t + X_t dP(t, T)  + d X_t  dP(t,T)   \\ 
  &=&  P(t, T) dX_t + X_t dP(t, T)  + dP(t,T) d X_t
  \end{eqnarray}
- Substitute the above result into $dV_t $.
  \begin{eqnarray}
  d V_t &=& \hat{ V_t }dP(t,T)  -  \partial_x C(X_t, \kappa, v(t, T) )  X_t dP(t, T) \nonumber \\
  && \quad + \partial_x C(X_t, \kappa, v(t, T) )  X_t dP(t, T) \nonumber \\
  && \quad + \partial_x C(X_t, \kappa, v(t, T) )  P(t, T)  dX_t  \nonumber \\
  && \quad + \partial_x C(X_t, \kappa, v(t, T) ) dP(t, T) dX_t \\
  &=& \left( \hat{ V_t } - X_t \partial_x C(X_t, \kappa, v(t, T) ) \right) dP(t, T) \nonumber \\
  && \quad + \partial_x C(X_t, \kappa, v(t, T) ) d P(t, S) \\
  &=& \left( \hat{ V_t } - \frac{P(t, S)}{P(t, T)}  \partial_x C(X_t, \kappa, v(t, T) ) \right) dP(t, T) \nonumber \\
  && \quad + \partial_x C(X_t, \kappa, v(t, T) ) d P(t, S) 
  \end{eqnarray}

$\square$

---

### (4) My answer

- (2) assumes that the portfolio $(\xi^T_t, \xi^S_t)_{t \in [0, T]}$ is self-financing, i.e.
  \begin{eqnarray}
  dV_t=\xi^T_t dP(t, T) + \xi^S_t  dP(t, S)
  \end{eqnarray}
- One also has another expression of $dV_t$ by (3).
  \begin{eqnarray}
  d V_t &=&\left( \hat{ V_t } - \frac{P(t, S)}{P(t, T)}  \partial_x C(X_t, \kappa, v(t, T) ) \right) dP(t, T) \nonumber \\
  && \quad + \partial_x C(X_t, \kappa, v(t, T) ) d P(t, S) 
  \end{eqnarray}
- item Comparing above two equations, one reaches the following equations.
  \begin{eqnarray}
  \xi^S_t  &=&  \partial_x C(X_t, \kappa, v(t, T) ) \\
  \xi^T_t &=&  \hat{ V_t } - \frac{P(t, S)}{P(t, T)}  \partial_x C(X_t, \kappa, v(t, T) ) \\
  &=&  \hat{ V_t } - X_t  \partial_x C(X_t, \kappa, v(t, T) ) \\
  &=&  \hat{ V_t } - X_t \xi^S_t 
  \end{eqnarray}
- Recall the result of (1), $C(X_t, \kappa, v(t, T) ) $ and the result of (2), $\hat{ V_t }=C(X_t, \kappa, v(t, T) ) $.
  \begin{eqnarray}
  C(X_t, \kappa, v(t, T) ) &=& \frac{ P(t,S) }{ P(t, T) }  N\left(   \frac{v}{2}  +  \frac{1}{v} \log \frac{P(t,S) }{\kappa \ P(t,T)} \right)  \nonumber \\
  && \qquad -  \kappa N\left( - \frac{v}{2}  +  \frac{1}{v} \log \frac{P(t,S) }{\kappa\ P(t,T)}\right)  \\
  &=& X_t  N\left(   \frac{v}{2}  +  \frac{1}{v} \log \frac{X_t}{\kappa } \right)  \nonumber \\
  && \qquad - \kappa N\left( - \frac{v}{2}  +  \frac{1}{v} \log \frac{X_t }{\kappa }\right)  \\
  \hat{ V_t } - X_t N\left(   \frac{v}{2}  +  \frac{1}{v} \log \frac{X_t}{\kappa } \right) &=& - \kappa N\left( - \frac{v}{2}  +  \frac{1}{v} \log \frac{X_t }{\kappa }\right)  
  \end{eqnarray}
- Comparing the above equation to $\xi^T_t $, one reaches the following equations.
  \begin{eqnarray}
  \xi^S_t  &=&  N\left(   \frac{v}{2}  +  \frac{1}{v} \log \frac{X_t}{\kappa } \right) \\
  &=&  N\left(   \frac{v(t, T) }{2}  +  \frac{1}{v(t, T) } \log \frac{P(t, S)}{\kappa \ P(t, T)} \right) \\
  \xi^T_t &=&  - \kappa N\left( - \frac{v}{2}  +  \frac{1}{v} \log \frac{X_t }{\kappa }\right)  \\
   &=&  - \kappa N\left( - \frac{v(t, T)}{2}  +  \frac{1}{v(t, T)} \log \frac{P(t, S) }{\kappa \ P(t, T) }\right) 
  \end{eqnarray}

$\square$